# Translating Java AES encryption to nodejs, but 16 bytes missing after encryption

Tags: java, node.js, cryptojs, aes-gcm

I am now coding a nodejs server, and require to call api from the java server, the encryption code provided was written in java hence I need to translate the code into nodejs with crypto.

The code in java is as following

```
    public static String encrypt(byte[] contentByte, byte[] key) throws Exception {
        SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(key, "AES");
        byte[] encrypted = null;
        try {
            SecureRandom secureRandom = new SecureRandom(); 
            byte[] iv = new byte[12];
            secureRandom.nextBytes(iv);
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(AES_GCM_NOPADDING); 
            GCMParameterSpec parameterSpec = new GCMParameterSpec("tLen":128, iv); 
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, skeySpec, parameterSpec);
            encrypted = cipher.doFinal(contentByte); 

            System.out.println(encrypted.length);
            // the remaining code is not important so I stop here
        }
String content = "hello world";
String encrypt_string = encrypt(content.getBytes(),  decodedBytes); //the decodedbytes is the buffer of private key
```

The length printed is 27 for "hello world"

I then rewrite it with nodejs

```
var crypto = require("crypto");

key = Buffer.from(key, "base64") 

let byte_data = `hello world`
byte_data = Buffer.from(byte_data, 'utf-8')
const iv = crypto.randomBytes(12)
const cipher = crypto.createCipheriv("aes-256-gcm", key, iv)  //the key is not valid for non 256 algorithm
let crypt = cipher.update(byte_data,"", "base64");
crypt += cipher.final("base64");
crypt_byte = Buffer.from(crypt, "base64")
console.log(crypt_byte.length)
```

the length printed is 11.

I wonder is the `GCMParameterSpec(128, iv)` missing in the nodejs code as 128 bits is 16 bytes, but refer to the crypto document, in crypto.createCipheriv("aes-256-gcm", key, iv), it has a default authentication tag length at 16 with gcm. Or is there other things that is wrong on my code.

Comment: GCM automatically generates an authentication tag during encryption. The tag is needed for decryption. In the Java code, this tag is _implicitly_ appended to the ciphertext. In the NodeJS code this does not happen, instead the tag must be determined _explicitly_ with `cipher.getAuthTag()` (which is currently missing!). Since GCM does not pad, the ciphertext length is the same as the plaintext length, so for the plaintext _hello world_ and a 16 bytes authentication tag, the Java code gives an 11 + 16 = 27 bytes result and the NodeJS code an 11 bytes result.

Comment: @Topaco But how to add the authentication tag into the encrypted buffer in nodejs, as getAuthTag() has to run after .final(), I dont know how and where should I add it, I am a pretty layman on crytography

Comment: I don't see the problem. When encrypting with NodeJS, the tag is determined with `cipher.getAuthTag()`. When decrypting with NodeJS, it is set with `decipher.setAuthTag(buffer[, encoding])`. When decrypting with Java, ciphertext and tag must be concatenated beforehand in the order `ciphertext | tag`.

Answer (score 1):

The below codes are full running examples of an AES 256 GCM encryption in Java and NodeJs with "Crypto".

**The codes are not optimized regarding ciphertext-handling** but show explicitly how to handle with (randomly) generated nonce (or IV), ciphertext with and without GCM tag on encryption and decryption side.

Kindly note that there is **no exception handling** - just take the codes as "educational".

This is an output:

```
AES GCM 256 String encryption with random key
plaintext:  The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
encryptionKey (Base64): /zTcqOfE8PdzrYmo6V9+YkWynSbDqqKo5VOrJzwDWME=

* * * Encryption * * *
ciphertext: qlzHXt+76TP8aoFM:C317D1/LQ1wGCOXRX/Z/9+hYR7XtcsEH3fGNOevGiia4/tVW6TlU9zXZ1A==:SCRyTSzXLo0B0TB2ycl5Sg==
output is (Base64) nonce : (Base64) ciphertext : (Base64) gcmTag

* * * Decryption * * *
decryptionKey (Base64): /zTcqOfE8PdzrYmo6V9+YkWynSbDqqKo5VOrJzwDWME=
ciphertext (Base64): qlzHXt+76TP8aoFM:C317D1/LQ1wGCOXRX/Z/9+hYR7XtcsEH3fGNOevGiia4/tVW6TlU9zXZ1A==:SCRyTSzXLo0B0TB2ycl5Sg==
input is (Base64) nonce : (Base64) ciphertext : (Base64) gcmTag
plaintext:  The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
```

Java:

```
import javax.crypto.BadPaddingException;
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException;
import javax.crypto.NoSuchPaddingException;
import javax.crypto.spec.GCMParameterSpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException;
import java.security.InvalidKeyException;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.SecureRandom;
import java.util.Base64;

public class AesGcm256StringEncryption {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, IllegalBlockSizeException, InvalidKeyException, BadPaddingException, InvalidAlgorithmParameterException, NoSuchPaddingException {
        System.out.println("AES GCM 256 String encryption with random key");

        String plaintext = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog";
        System.out.println("plaintext:  " + plaintext);

        // generate random key
        byte[] encryptionKey = generateRandomAesKey();
        String encryptionKeyBase64 = base64Encoding(encryptionKey);
        System.out.println("encryptionKey (Base64): " + encryptionKeyBase64);

        // encryption
        System.out.println("\n* * * Encryption * * *");
        String ciphertextBase64 = aesGcmEncryptToBase64(encryptionKey, plaintext);
        System.out.println("ciphertext: " + ciphertextBase64);
        System.out.println("output is (Base64) nonce : (Base64) ciphertext : (Base64) gcmTag");

        // decryption
        System.out.println("\n* * * Decryption * * *");
        String decryptionKeyBase64 = encryptionKeyBase64; // full
        String ciphertextDecryptionBase64 = ciphertextBase64;
        System.out.println("decryptionKey (Base64): " + decryptionKeyBase64);
        byte[] decryptionKey = base64Decoding(decryptionKeyBase64);
        System.out.println("ciphertext (Base64): " + ciphertextDecryptionBase64);
        System.out.println("input is (Base64) nonce : (Base64) ciphertext : (Base64) gcmTag");
        String decryptedtext = aesGcmDecryptFromBase64(decryptionKey, ciphertextDecryptionBase64);
        System.out.println("plaintext:  " + decryptedtext);
    }

    private static byte[] generateRandomAesKey() {
        SecureRandom secureRandom = new SecureRandom();
        byte[] key = new byte[32];
        secureRandom.nextBytes(key);
        return key;
    }

    private static byte[] generateRandomNonce() {
        SecureRandom secureRandom = new SecureRandom();
        byte[] nonce = new byte[12];
        secureRandom.nextBytes(nonce);
        return nonce;
    }

    private static String aesGcmEncryptToBase64(byte[] key, String data) throws NoSuchPaddingException, NoSuchAlgorithmException,
            InvalidAlgorithmParameterException, InvalidKeyException, BadPaddingException, IllegalBlockSizeException {
        byte[] nonce = generateRandomNonce();
        SecretKeySpec secretKeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(key, "AES");
        GCMParameterSpec gcmParameterSpec = new GCMParameterSpec(16 * 8, nonce);
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/GCM/PKCS5Padding");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKeySpec, gcmParameterSpec);
        byte[] ciphertextWithTag = cipher.doFinal(data.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
        byte[] ciphertext = new byte[(ciphertextWithTag.length-16)];
        byte[] gcmTag = new byte[16];
        System.arraycopy(ciphertextWithTag, 0, ciphertext, 0, (ciphertextWithTag.length - 16));
        System.arraycopy(ciphertextWithTag, (ciphertextWithTag.length-16), gcmTag, 0, 16);
        String nonceBase64 = base64Encoding(nonce);
        String ciphertextBase64 = base64Encoding(ciphertext);
        String gcmTagBase64 = base64Encoding(gcmTag);
        return nonceBase64 + ":" + ciphertextBase64 + ":" + gcmTagBase64;
    }

    private static String aesGcmDecryptFromBase64(byte[] key, String data) throws NoSuchPaddingException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidAlgorithmParameterException, InvalidKeyException, BadPaddingException, IllegalBlockSizeException {
        String[] parts = data.split(":", 0);
        byte[] nonce = base64Decoding(parts[0]);
        byte[] ciphertextWithoutTag = base64Decoding(parts[1]);
        byte[] gcmTag = base64Decoding(parts[2]);
        byte[] encryptedData = concatenateByteArrays(ciphertextWithoutTag, gcmTag);
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/GCM/PKCS5Padding");
        SecretKeySpec secretKeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(key, "AES");
        GCMParameterSpec gcmParameterSpec = new GCMParameterSpec(16 * 8, nonce);
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKeySpec, gcmParameterSpec);
        return new String(cipher.doFinal(encryptedData));
    }

    private static String base64Encoding(byte[] input) {
        return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(input);
    }
    private static byte[] base64Decoding(String input) {
        return Base64.getDecoder().decode(input);
    }

    public static byte[] concatenateByteArrays(byte[] a, byte[] b) {
        return ByteBuffer
                .allocate(a.length + b.length)
                .put(a).put(b)
                .array();
    }
}
```

NodeJs:

```
var crypto = require('crypto');

console.log('AES GCM 256 String encryption with random key full');

var plaintext = 'The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog';
console.log('plaintext: ', plaintext);

// generate random key
var encryptionKey = generateRandomAesKey();
var encryptionKeyBase64 = base64Encoding(encryptionKey);
console.log('encryptionKey (Base64): ', encryptionKeyBase64);

console.log('\n* * * Encryption * * *');

var ciphertextBase64 = aesGcmEncryptToBase64(encryptionKey, plaintext);
console.log('ciphertext (Base64): ' + ciphertextBase64);
console.log('output is (Base64) nonce : (Base64) ciphertext : (Base64) gcmTag');

console.log('\n* * * Decryption * * *');
var decryptionKeyBase64 = encryptionKeyBase64;
var ciphertextDecryptionBase64 = ciphertextBase64;
console.log('decryptionKey (Base64): ', decryptionKeyBase64);
console.log('ciphertext (Base64): ', ciphertextDecryptionBase64);
console.log('input is (Base64) nonce : (Base64) ciphertext : (Base64) gcmTag');
var decryptedtext = aesGcmDecryptFromBase64(encryptionKey, ciphertextBase64);
console.log('plaintext: ', decryptedtext);

function aesGcmEncryptToBase64(key, data) {
  var nonce = generateRandomNonce();
  const cipher = crypto.createCipheriv('aes-256-gcm', key, nonce);
  let encryptedBase64 = '';
  cipher.setEncoding('base64');
  cipher.on('data', (chunk) => encryptedBase64 += chunk);
  cipher.on('end', () => {
  // do nothing console.log(encryptedBase64);
  // Prints: some clear text data
  });
  cipher.write(data);
  cipher.end();
  var nonceBase64 = base64Encoding(nonce);
  var gcmTagBase64 = base64Encoding(cipher.getAuthTag());
  return nonceBase64 + ':' + encryptedBase64 + ':' + gcmTagBase64;
}

function aesGcmDecryptFromBase64(key, data) {
  var dataSplit = data.split(":");
  var nonce = base64Decoding(dataSplit[0]);
  var ciphertext = dataSplit[1];
  var gcmTag = base64Decoding(dataSplit[2]);
  const decipher = crypto.createDecipheriv('aes-256-gcm', key, nonce);
  decipher.setAuthTag(gcmTag);
  let decrypted = '';
  decipher.on('readable', () => {
    while (null !== (chunk = decipher.read())) {
      decrypted += chunk.toString('utf8');
    }
  });
  decipher.on('end', () => {
  // do nothing console.log(decrypted);
  });
  decipher.write(ciphertext, 'base64');
  decipher.end();
  return decrypted;
}  

function generateRandomAesKey() {
  return crypto.randomBytes(32);
}

function generateRandomNonce() {
  return crypto.randomBytes(12);
}

function base64Encoding(input) {
  return input.toString('base64');
}

function base64Decoding(input) {
  return Buffer.from(input, 'base64')
}
```